# Can't work datetimepicker bootstap 3

Tags: jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

I just pass value view js but can't 
Here is my code...

```js
$(function() {
  var ddate = document.getElementById("datetimepicker4").value;
  $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: ddate,
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
});
```

```html
<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @weBer Error fixed.